# executing a function as an ifelse condition

Tags: r, function, if-statement

In the following example, I define 'myFunc', then test for two error conditions. If neither error condition is met, I want 'myFunc' to execute.

```
State<-rep(c("NY","NJ"),times=5)
Test<-rep(c("LSAT", "MCAT", "GRE","TOEFL","ACT"), times=2)
Grade<-trunc(rep((seq(from=500, to=600,length.out=10))))
dat<-data.frame(Test,State,Grade)
statelist<-c("NY","NJ","CA")
testlist<-c("LSAT", "MCAT", "GRE","TOEFL","ACT","VSAT")

myFunc<-function(state,test)
{
  dat<-subset(dat,subset=(State==state & Test==test))
}

ifelse(!state %in% statelist, stop("invalid state"),
       ifelse(!test %in% testlist, stop("invalid test"),
              ifelse(myFunc)
```

When I test the function with the following variables:

```
myFunc("NY", "GRE")
```

I get this error message:

```
    Error: unexpected symbol in:
"              ifelse(myFunc)       
myFunc"
```

Also, when I test with an invalid state, 'NN',

> myFunc("NN", "GRE")

the "invalid state" message is not triggered, and the same error message is generated that I got when I used a valid state.

Is there a problem with the way I've organized my three ifelse statements? I want to keep the two error checks out of the function, so that the function only deals with subsetting.

Comment: 1-Your last `ifelse` doesn't make any sense. 2- there are no variables called "state" or "test" in your global environment. 3- Even if your last `ifelse` was correct, you are missing at least 2 parentheses

Comment: Check out `?stopifnot`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I would do it, I switched to an `if` statement since that made more sense to me

```
myFunc <- function(state,test){
  dat <- subset(dat,subset=(State==state & Test==test))
  if(!state %in% statelist)
    {stop("invalid state")}
  if(!test %in% testlist)
    {stop("invalid test")}
  else 
    {return(dat)}
}

R> myFunc("NY", "GRE")
  Test State Grade
3  GRE    NY   522
R> myFunc("NN", "GRE")
Error in myFunc("NN", "GRE") : invalid state
R> myFunc("NY", "GREY")
Error in myFunc("NY", "GREY") : invalid test
```

Comment: I would put the subsetting opertion inside the `else` statement so it is only evaluated when both inputs are valid, otherwise it looks nice, +1

Answer (score 0):

There are better ways of handling errors, but here is how to fix your function. You need the ifelse inside your function.

```
myFunc<-function(state,test)
{
  ifelse(!state %in% statelist, stop("invalid state", call. = FALSE),
         ifelse(!test %in% testlist, stop("invalid test", call. = FALSE), return(subset(dat,subset=(State==state & Test==test)))))  
}

 myFunc("NY", "GRE")
 > Test State Grade
 > 3  GRE    NY   522

 myFunc("NN", "GRE")
 > Error: invalid state 

 myFunc("NY", "Cake")
 > Error: invalid test
```